# KeySetView loop by value

Tags: java, loops, concurrenthashmap

I am searching about Concurrent Set implementation by ConcurrentHashMap, and found something strange.
My code:

```
Set<String> keySetView = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
keySetView.add("1");
keySetView.add("2");
keySetView.add("3");

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1","2","3"));
for (String a : keySetView){
    System.out.println("keySetView value = " + a);
    keySetView.removeAll(arr);
    System.out.println("keySetView after remove size = " + keySetView.size());
}
```

Expected result:

```
keySetView value = 1
keySetView after remove size = 0
```

But when I run code:

```
keySetView value = 1
keySetView after remove size = 0
keySetView value = 2
keySetView after remove size = 0
```

Why does it still show element 2 when we already remove all elements in my Set?

Comment: Editing the array object inside a foreach loop is not a good tactic. Your program may also crash.

Comment: yes, this is only debug for checking Concurrent Set (modify Set while loop). But I want to know why element 2 still show after removeAll?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `foreach` loop is implemented via iterators, which already points to the next value after the first value is extracted for the first loop iteration. So when you call removeAll the iterator already has the next value. Now this is the most likely reason, **however**, this is an JVM implementation detail that one should never rely on as it cannot be guaranteed that another implementation e.g. OpenJDK vs OracleJDK will not use some sort of optimisation for `foreach` loops. The only safe way to iterate removing elements is to use the iterator explicitly:

```
Iterator<T> it = set.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    T t = it.next();
    it.remove(); // or remove until empty
}
```